# How to provide driver support, without upgrading the kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, wifi, drivers

Ahoy friends.
Currently i'm using CentOS on my server, but i also have some latest hardware built in.
In this case i got an Intel AX200 Wireless card, to discover other WiFi networks.
Unfortunately this wireless card is only being supported since kernel version 5.1.0.
So my question is, is there any way to provide driver support for this wireless card, even using the 3.x kernels from CentOS? Or do i have to upgrade the kernel to another version, even having trouble with dkms and this stuff?

Comment: You can check out backports: Sometimes fixes and drivers are back ported into older kernel. If not and you don't want to do it your self, then you will have to upgrade.

Comment: What's wrong with upgrading the kernel exactly? I use elrepo kernel-ml on CentOS, and DKMS works completely flawlessly, with both VirtualBox and OpenAFS.